# OSI and Open Source SE

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, liaisons

According to [this Area 51 Discussion Post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19452/could-this-be-the-official-site-for-the-open-source-initiative), the Open Source Initiative was contacted regarding the use of their logo. In the end, the OSI was interested in promoting this site, hoping to use it to discuss Open Source related topics.

> The OSI currently provides mailing lists and email contacts for people to ask questions related to open source issues: copyright/licensing/patents, funding models, community development & management, etc. These lists and emails require a significant investment to review and respond to by the limited number of OSI Board Directors. The OSI has been considering creating a forum to help capture and share the wisdom of the larger open source community, while also focusing discussions in one location. There are several very good discussions happening all over the internet on open source software and development (Reddit, specific project sites, etc.), but this site would enjoy the recognition and engagement from the OSI community and Directors.
>
> In addition, the OSI would promote this site (much like Ubuntu does with AskUbuntu, http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/support/ask-ubuntu/), hopefully adding credibility to the discussions, awareness of this resource across the broader open source community, and incentive for participation.
>
> Please know, the OSI would in no way want to control or direct the discussions, topics, etc. Our only role would be to promote use and add our perspectives to enhance and further knowledge around the open source movement.

I would like to know from those who were in contact with the OSI, what the status is. I have a couple questions:

- Does the OSI know about the condition of this site? That we are in the beta phase?
- Is the OSI still interested in promoting this site?
- Have key members of the OSI (i.e. Directors and key people) been invited to the Private Beta here?

Comment: Yes I'd particularly be interested to know if OSI have been invited to Private Beta, and if not whether someone will (and let them know that the next few days are critical to deciding whether we proceed).

Comment: @trichoplax I exchanged some mails with someone at OSI and someone at SE about the subject, the last I knew they were in talks to figure out how the collaboration could work. However judging from the [minutes of the OSI board meeting in february](http://opensource.org/minutes20150204) this might have halted (ctrl+f for "stack"). I don't want to speak out of turn though and will thus refrain from posting an answer. I will however say that at least one key member of OSI has made an account on here, I'll see if I can bring this thread to their attention.

Comment: @overactor Have any idea what MOU was in their minutes?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I don't, so I guess it could still mean a lot of things.

Comment: Oh well, in chat we determined it to be Memorandum Of Understanding. With that, I'm scared about the 9 NO votes (Compared with 0 YES votes)

Comment: @Zizouz212 oh, you meant what MOU means... In any case, since we don't know the exact conditions, it's impossible to say what this really means, we'll have to wait for a statement from either OSI or SE.

Comment: @overactor I know that one of the community managers stumbled upon this post (they had made an edit) so hopefully this has been brought to the attention of the Stack Exchange team :)

Comment: Hi all, I see I cannot answer the question yet (only have a reputation of 1), but the quote listed above was from me in my role as GM at the OSI and we are indeed still interested. As @trichoplax noted, when we first raised this with the Board is was not approved as we needed to formalize the relationship between the OSI and S.E. through a Memorandum of Understanding/Agreement. This would clarify how the OSI marks/name would be used, the role of the OSI in moderation, commenting and structure the relationship (e.g. "The OSI does not endorse the comments made...").

Comment: @massonpj Hi! Thanks for reaching out! Do you think we could speak in chat? I would love to talk.

Comment: @Zizouz212 sure

Comment: Just give me a second, we're just trying to bring you into the chatroom :)

Comment: [Relevant chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25380/discussion-with-osi)