# Where can I find Free/Open software, libraries and media?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

This site doesn't allow questions that ask us to recommend Free & Open works such as software, libraries, media, or services. There are a few reasons why these are not constructive questions:

- They are usually quite subjective. No one can tell you what the 'best' library is; you will need to try a few and decide.
- Unless the request is extremely specific these questions are just setting everyone up for disappointment when the question asker says to those who are trying to help "That's not what I was thinking of." We're not mind-readers!
- In general no one will be able to find what you're after faster than you can yourself. Even the best intentioned of these questions end up just resulting in someone shifting their work to someone else.

But we still want to help! This post contains a long list of websites where you might be able to find what you're after.

Comment: Relevant SE sites: [softwarerecs.se] (for software/libraries) and [opendata.se] (for data)

Answer (score 3):

## Software & libraries

### General (non-language specific) sites

- [GitHub](https://github.com/): search over 28 million repositories. Note that while most repositories are Free/Open licensed, not all are

### Javascript

- [microjs](http://microjs.com/): search for libraries which are under 5kb when compressed
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) ([npmsearch](http://npmsearch.com/)): npm is the home of Node.js' package manager, but you can find many libraries which work in browser based JS too. For example, it is now the official home for [jQuery plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/jquery-plugin). npm's search is unranked, so you may find npmsearch more useful for finding well-maintained libraries.

### JVM (Java, Clojure, Groovy, Scala)

- [Sonatype central](http://central.sonatype.org/)
- [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/)

### Perl

- [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/): The Comprehensive Perl Archive Network, online since 1995

### Python

- [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi): The Python Package Index, with over 67 thousand packages

### .NET

- [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages): A central repository for .NET packages

## Media

### All media

- [Creative Commons](http://search.creativecommons.org/): a meta-search engine, helps you search other search engines for CC licensed media
- [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page): search over 28 million images, sounds and videos.

### 3D models

- [OpenGameArt.org](http://opengameart.org/): includes 2D and 3D art, as well as music, available (and searchable by) a variety of licenses

## Hardware

### Products

- ?

### Designs

- ?

Comment: Why did you move it to an answer?

Comment: @curiousdannii The list itself fits better in an answer than in a question.