# Availability of open source software for particular field of interest

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about availability of free and open source software for particular field of interest on topic? I mean questions like "Is there FOSS for controlling the Space Shuttle?" and more generally the type of question like this: "Is there FOSS for doing ABC?" (substitute an activity - like "autonomous driving", "quadcopter autopilot" etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I think that would come under our existing close reason about *off-site resources*:

> Questions that ask for off-site resources, or for a recommendation of an open source service or product are off-topic because they don't directly concern an issue related to open source development. See: [What's wrong with "External Resources" questions?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/688/whats-wrong-with-external-resources-questionsfor) more information.

Asking whether there's software for a certain task would likely be construed as asking for an external resource, and would probably therefore be closed as off-topic. I can't see any easy way to rephrase it to bring it on-topic either, I'm afraid.

---

If you're looking for software for a specific purpose, and you have *specific* requirements for it, and you haven't been able to find it with your own research, you may be able to ask these questions at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). You can specify FOSS as one of the requirements. You should have a read of their [question asking guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before asking there.