# About asking the team searching question on the opensource SE site

Tags: discussion

I have seen the [tour page of opensource.stackexchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/tour) and want to know:

**Based on below photo,am i right that [my question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11566/about-team-searching-for-artificial-intelligence-startups-as-opensource-project), is related to **the community communication** section?** (Moderator's note: the linked question has since been deleted, so will only be visible to users with appropriate privileges.)

[image]

So if my question is not proper for the opensource SE site, if possible I like to know which SE site is proper to ask it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your questions sounds like you're recruiting workers for a startup. That is off topic everywhere on Stack Exchange. There is **no site** where that would be on topic.

Here on the Open Source site, we're not just about Open Source licenses. We also have questions and answers about community aspects of Open Source, like how to collaborate well in an Open Source environment. Questions about how to grow an Open Source community can also be within our scope, but it's difficult to ask such questions in a productive way. I do not think your question falls under any of these cases.

I see three way to read your questions, and none of them are a good fit here.

1. Your post can be seen as an ad that says “please join my project!”

   That is not even a question. This is a question-and-answer site. Also, we don't like ads. If you want employees for your startup, go to a job board and hire an employee.
2. Your post can be seen as a request for resources that says “Where can I find a community that is interested in these topics?”

   That is a question, but questions that ask for external resources are [out of scope](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/688).
3. Your post can be seen as a question about *how* to attract contributors to a project.

   While that might be within scope of this site, there's an unfortunate answer: most Open Source projects are not very interesting, and never get any users or contributions.

   Think about what motivates someone to contribute to an open source project. Usually, this is because a user of a program has a problem with that program, and wants to fix it. However, your “startup” doesn't have any users that could turn into contributors. You don't even have a software that could get users. All you have is an idea.

   Because there's no useful answer other than “build something awesome first” or ”just be lucky“, questions like “How do I attract contributors to my project” aren't a good fit here either.

Comment: I may get a t-shirt made up with "**Build something awesome first**" on it.  That is a fantastic one-line summary of the problem.