# Asking a question about an open source dataset of digitized correspondence

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, asking-questions

A couple of months ago, I asked the [following question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/21119/back-and-forth-emails-and-letters) on Open Data (Beta) SE:

> For a research project, I am currently looking for datasets that
> consists of large amounts of e-mails, text messages, or OCR-processed
> letters that were written as part of a conversational exchange between
> two people.
>
> There are quite a few open datasets that include a (significant
> amount) of emails. For instance, one has the [Enron dataset](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/), the [Jeb Bush dataset](https://github.com/hical/sample-dataset),
> and the [Hillary
> Clinton dataset](https://wikileaks.org/clinton-emails/). However, these datasets are not exactly what I'm
> looking for.
>
> I'd like to have a dataset that consists of a large amount of
> (written) conversations between exactly two people. The emails should
> alternate between these two people, with one email (or letter or text
> message) for each person, each time.
>
> **Question**: do such open datasets exist? If so, where can I find them?

Unfortunately, the question did not attract a lot of attention and it hasn't been answered so far. I wonder whether this question is also approproate for the Open Source SE venue. I hope it is because I am looking for an open source dataset that consists of email or digitized mail correspondence between two people. However, I am not a frequent visitor of this particular SE page, so I thought it'd be good to inquire here on Meta to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When voting to close a question, we actually have a specific reason that would apply to such a question:

> Questions that ask for off-site resources, or for a recommendation of an open source service or product *are off-topic* because they don't directly concern an issue related to open source development. See: [What's wrong with external resources questions?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/688/whats-wrong-with-external-resources-questions) for more information.

So, unfortunately, I don't think that question will be a good fit here. The linked meta question contains some reasoning behind this guideline.

Comment: thank you for your answer - I see it isn't a good fit based on these guidlines. Do you perhaps know another SE page where the question would suit well?

Comment: @MaxMuller The only SE site I'm familiar with that encourages asking for recommendations of offsite resources is [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Asking for datasets **might** be on topic there, but I'm not a member of that community, so I don't really know. I guess you should take the same approach you took here, and ask on their [meta site](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/) first.

Comment: @MaxMuller and while we're on the subject, **thank you** for having the nous and courtesy to ask in meta, instead of just posting the question and then getting annoyed when it gets closed.  It really is appreciated, and I hope you do find the right place to post the question - and get some good answers.