# Open Source is leaving beta

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

Management has been reviewing all of the sites that are currently in Beta
to determine which sites are ready to lose that label and join other
graduated sites on the Stack Exchange Network. Based on the longevity of
our site, the number of open questions, and the number of open questions
that have at least one upvoted answer, Open Source is ready to leave Beta.
This will happen on 16 December 2021.

What this will mean is that the Beta label will be removed from our site.
At some point in 2022 (or even 2023), we will also have a graduation
election; all existing moderators will
be retired, and elections will be held *de novo* (though there is no bar on
your current moderation team standing, should we so choose).

The usual site re-skinning will not accompany our
graduation. At some point down the road it is hoped that we'll get a light
re-design to move us a little away from the beta skin, but it won't happen
on the 16th.

Apparently, we can refuse this crown, if we so desire. If you'd like to
argue for us remaining in beta, I'd ask you to open a new meta question.

Comment: Great news! I'm not the most active user here, but this is one of my favorite SE sites. Moving out of beta is a testament to the health of the community built here.

Comment: FWIW, here's the official announcement on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/223467

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about we now finally change the name so that Free Software doesn't feel excluded?

Previous discussions:

- [Alternative site name brainstorming](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300/alternative-site-name-brainstorming)
- [More site name brainstorming - Part II](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/511/more-site-name-brainstorming-part-ii)
- [More site name brainstorming - Part III](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/542/more-site-name-brainstorming-part-iii)

I still think "Free & Open" would be the best name!

Sadly my question never received an answer from staff: [What are the criteria for which a name will be considered acceptable?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/what-are-the-criteria-for-which-a-name-will-be-considered-acceptable)

Comment: Speaking personally, I too would still like to get *Free* into the name.  I thought *FLOSS* was snappier than *Free and Open*, but the latter's definitely an improvement on the *status quo*.  Do you fancy floating a new question about a name change?

Comment: @MadHatter I would be, if I knew that the staff were actually open to it. They shut down our attempts 6 years ago with no good explanation. Now a lot of the staff have changed, so maybe they're open to it now?